# Date Formatting in Javascript/Classic ASP using DateAdd()

Tags: javascript, date, asp-classic, date-format

All I want to do, is format dates in the mm/dd/yyyy format using the DateAdd function.  I have this code which is subtracting days to the "LastBusinessDate" session variable to make it look like the values were from previous days and not static dates.

```
DataArray[0] = new Array("<%=DateAdd("d",-1,Session("LastBusinessDate"))%>","Test Test","001","PRO000002",1);
```

the problem is this will return in the format of m/d/yyyy if the session("LastBusinessDate") value is single digits such as 4/1/2013, when i want it returned as 04/01/2013.  I have tried using

```
DateFormat(DateAdd("d",-1,Session("LastBusinessDate")),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

as well as

```
DateAdd("d",-1,DateFormat(Session("LastBusinessDate"),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

and also creating a function, just passing in the number of days to subtract from the date and returning the new date formatted but that doesn't work either.

```
function formatBizDate(byDays){
    var byDays = byDays;
    var dateChange = Session("LastBusinessDate");
    dateChange = dateFormat(dateChange,"mm/dd/yyyy");
    dateChange = DateAdd("d",byDays,dateChange);
    return dateChange;
}
```

no idea where to go from here.

Comment: You need uppercase `MM` in your format string: `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: good catch, that's an amateur mistake on my part, but switching the mm for MM in all scenarios above still errors out and doesn't return a value for me

Comment: What's the new error?

Comment: all i'm getting in code is error '800a000d' which i believe is a type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBScript date format function is FormatDateTime (not "DateFormat"), but it's very limited: it will only return one of four system formats, and two of those are for times, not dates. None of the formats will add leading zeros if that's not how your system date formats are set up.

It's not entirely clear to me whether you're trying to do this formatting server-side (i.e. with VBScript) or client-side (i.e. with JavaScript). I can't help you with the latter, but for the former, I'd suggest something like:

```vbs
Function DateFormat(d)
  If IsDate(d) Then
    DateFormat = Right(100+Month(d),2) &"/"& Right(100+Day(d),2) &"/"& Year(d)
  Else
    DateFormat = d
  End If
End Function
```

Strictly speaking this will actually return a string, not a date, but converting it to a date (via `CDate` or `DateValue`) will remove your carefully-added leading zeroes.

Comment: this works exactly how I needed it to, thank you very much @Martha for your response.

Answer (score 2):

in Custom Date Format `mm` represents `Minutes` and `MM` represents `Month`

This :

`mm/dd/yyyy`

should be

`MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

I can see this is an old question, but I had a LOT of issues with this myself, because the output format of DateAdd() is dependent on the locale settings on the webserver, so I thought I'd share anyway: I finally got this fixed by forcing the locale on the server session by injecting this code snippet on all asp-pages:

'Set the server locale to Danish
Session.LCID = 1030

Source: https://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/date-time-settings.htm (this page also holds a list of country codes)